# Separate Theme on Mobile for Magento

Tags: android, iphone, magento, blackberry

Please, how do I use another theme for only mobile devices on Magento?

I have tried using the exception but it doesn't show up and tried changing it on the "Design" page under settings.

Any is appreciated.

The main reason why I want to use another theme on mobiles is the slider. The slider doesn't display correctly on mobiles.

Thanks.

Comment: if you just want to hide the slider, why not hide it in css for devices smaller than XX pixels wide?

Comment: sounds like a good idea... but would like to exhaust all other options first. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

In `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes` click on *Add Exception* buttons and in the
- *Matched Expression* add smth like `iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini` or a more complicated/accurate expression
- *Value* field add the name of your mobile theme.
The clear your cache.

But why don't you use a responsive slider, they are plenty on [magento connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=responsive+slider&pl=0)

Comment: I've tried using the exception, still doesn't work... the slider is actually responsive, I just dont get why it doesnt crop to fit. It only shows part of the screen.